# Fortran errors - Complex argument bessel function

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, cygwin, gfortran, bessel-functions

I have been having some trouble getting some fortran code I was given working. This code uses an external library, NUMERICAL_LIBRARIES, by Rogue Wave in order to implement a bessel function with complex argument. I have attempted to contact Rogue Wave but they have ignored my emails so far.

I downloaded a bessel function library from, https://jblevins.org/mirror/amiller/ (toms644.zip), in an attempt to get an open source version working. However, I have not been able to get this code integrated with the code given to me.

Compiling the code with this statement in cygwin:

`gfortran "pulse9_sili_oneTube - Copy.f90" -o  "CBESSEL.F90" -o pressureWaveModel`

gives me this error statement:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /tmp/cc0Rqf3a.o:pulse9_sili_oneTube - Copy.f90:(.text+0x29d80): undefined reference to `cbesj_'
/tmp/cc0Rqf3a.o:pulse9_sili_oneTube - Copy.f90:(.text+0x29d80): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cbesj_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have linked the CBESSEL.F90 file to my main file:

```
INCLUDE "CBESSEL.F90"

USE Complex_Bessel
```

However, I cant even get the testing code running so perhaps my compiler is set up wrong? Compiling the test code gives me error saying it cant open the module file, do I need to somehow create a module file? There were no useful instructions included with this code.

Any help you can provide would be super useful!!
Cheers.

Comment: Rogue Wave (now acquired by Perforce) sells the IMSL library, which is quite expensive. If you are willing to acquire a license, it should be straightforward to contact them to get a quote. They won't give you the code for free, of course.

Comment: Regarding the code from TOMS 644, note that when you call gfortran, there are two `-o` options, and you seem to be telling the compiler to overwrite the source CBESSEL.F90 with a binary object. This is wrong. You don't have to write a module, CBESSEL.F90 **is** a module. Just compile it before compiling your code, and link your code with the binary object CBESSEL.o. You don't have to INCLUDE anything.

Comment: FWIW, I can compile CBESSEL.F90 and then the test programs, without any error or warning, using Intel Fortran. With gfortran, it should look like `gfortran -c CBESSEL.F90` and then `gfortran "pulse9_sili_oneTube - Copy.f90" CBESSEL.o -o pressureWaveModel`.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, code from ACM TOMS is **not** open source. You may have a look at the [license](https://www.acm.org/publications/policies/software-copyright-notice), and [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/for-software-submitted-to-acm-toms-how-does-the-acm-software-license-agreement) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACM_Transactions_on_Mathematical_Software).

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut, thankyou for your help, I was able to get the Bessel function working with my code using your compiling statement. All I had to do was add "USE Complex_Bessel" to the subroutine that called the Bessel function and not to the main routine. Cheers!!

Comment: put the solution as answer not as comment